# How to getting in Dart the type mirror with the specified type arguments through reflection?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Sample code that explains problem.

```dart
import "dart:mirrors";    

void main() {
  var type = getTypeFromDeclaration();
  var typeArguments = getAnotherTypeArguments();
  var myType = reflectType(type, typeArguments);
}
```

How to getting in Dart the type mirror with the specified type arguments through reflection?

P.S.

I think that I don't need to explain "Why this need?" because we all know that this functionality required for the data hydration.

Also this is very useful in data codecs that used reflection for the better data consistency.

As you noticed, I will not explain why.

Comment: Related issue: http://dartbug.com/18139. But maybe exists other way that I don't know?

Answer (score 2):

First, I agree that it would be best if the mirror system allowed creating a type mirror of Map from the type mirrors of Foo and Bar and the class mirror of Map. That is currently not the case.

Without that, I don't think you can solve the problem as written.
There is no way to create a parameterized type with a type argument that is not known *as a type* at compile-time.

For completeness, I'll include a way to reflect a parameterized type if you know the type at compile time. If the type arguments can be represented as something else than a Type object or a TypeMirror object, you can build your own representation that allows operations like this.

If you can't use `reflectType(Map<Foo,Baz>)` because `Map<Foo,Baz>` is not a valid type literal, there is a small workaround to get a Type for any type: Have a class with a type parameter and a way to get the Type value of that parameter.

```dart
import "dart:mirrors";
class Typer<T> { Type get type => T; }
main() { 
  var mapStringInt = reflectType(new Typer<Map<String,int>>().type);
  print(mapStringInt);                // ClassMirror on 'Map'
  print(mapStringInt.typeArguments);  // [ClassMirror on 'String', ClassMirror on 'int']
  // That is: it's a TypeMirror on Map<String,int>.
}
```

Comment: I cannot use "reflectType(Map<Foo,Baz>)" becuase these arguments hand written in the source code (const Foo and const Baz). But I want work with variable arguments. reflectType(UnknownType, UnknownTypeArgumentList). This is not the same because the type arguments I want get from declarations but not write them constantly in the source code. You understand me? Your "Typer" can take type only as generic type argument. How I can use it if I don't know type before I wrote this code: var typeArgument = getType(); new Typer<List< typeArgument>>().type.